# how to call javascript function inside the controller in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code snippet below.

sample.js

```
    (function() {
    /*global angular */
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myapp', ['spinner'])
       .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function ($scope, $window ) {

    $scope.methodname = function() {
            if(something){
                /* Doing some operations */
            }
    };
    /* Here I need to define the callme javascript function */

   function callme(response){
       /* If I call like this, I'm getting error in console. */
    }

    }]);  /* Controller ends here */

    /* Creating a new anonymous function to perform some operations */
    (function () {
    'use strict';


     /* Edited */
   code.util.myHTTP(url, function (response) {

             // Adding response to session storage
            callme(response);

             }, function () {
               // Removing from session storage
        });

        })();
     }());
```

Here, I can't able to call callme javascript function inside angular controller . 
I'm getting error in console like

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: callme is not defined
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Edit:**

I need to use some controller parameters inside callme function, that's why I'm defining callme function inside controller.

I have run function in my js file already like below

```
.run(function($rootScope, $log, $window) {
});
```

How should I append myCtrl here?

Comment: what controller's parameters are used by callme ?

Comment: something like $window, $log

Comment: My requirement is like call anonymous function, on load there will be some api response, I need to call one method to process the response. because of these controller parameters, I wanted to define my method inside the contoller. Is there any alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: this response is returned by the controller ?

Comment: no this response is returned by ajax call which I m doing inside anonymous function

Comment: can you update your post with that ajax call ?

Comment: just edited my question with ajax call, pls check

Comment: why i m defining this callme method inside controller is to use $window for some operation

Comment: And what the `callme` method does in your controller ?

Answer (score 1):

**The dirty way**

First, if you want to use your your `callme`controller function, then you have to expose it. As you wrote it, it's still private. To make it public, just "append" it to your controller's scope (just as you did with `scope.methodname`) :

```
...
$scope.callme = function(){
...
}
..
```

Then, use this function in a module so that the controller could be reachable :

```
angular.module('amodule').run(['myCtrl ', function(myCtrl){
    myCtrl.callme();
}]);
```

**Another way**

The best thing to do is to use a factory as you want to share a service :

```
angular.module('myapp').factory('myservice', function(){
    function callme(){
        // TODO : implement the service
    }
    return {
        callme:callme
    };
});
```

Then in a new module, call that method :

```
angular.module('amodule').run(['myservice ', function(myservice){
    myservice.callme();
}]);
```

If you want to call that service outside angular (as you are wanting to do):

```
angular.injector(['myservice']).get('callme').call();
```

Edit :
You can declare inject the service or controller in one run. It will work.
Please, just keep in mind that injecting your controller in your module's `run` method is a result of bad design.
Use factories/services to share data/services.
I'm sure that with more code we can help your more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already run function which will do some operations. Can I use more than one run function in a same page/same file?

Comment: I have one more question which I edited. Can you please answer it?